# How to create a custom (frame) control that would consist of frame and label?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I want to create a reusable custom control that would could wrap around other elements. I want it to look similar to outlined entry but label should always stay in it's place and not move. For example, I would like to put entry in my custom frame control and it should look like this:

```
<custom:CustomFrameClass>
    <Entry></Entry>
</custom:CustomFrameClass>

public class CustomFrameClass : Frame
{
}
```

[Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2KuH.png)

At first I tried co create a content view with label and frame but then saw that if I put anything inside it, for example - entry, entry is simply put on top of the content view.

I don't want to draw a control but if I have to I would like to do it without third party libraries like SkiaSharp (if it is possible).

**EDIT:**
Came up with an answer using control template:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="CustomBorderApp.CustomFrame">
<ContentView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="FrameTemplate">
           
            <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="1" Margin="15" BackgroundColor="{TemplateBinding FrameColor}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Frame x:Name="frame" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="Black" HasShadow="False" Padding="10,15" BackgroundColor="{TemplateBinding FrameColor}">

                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                       
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Frame>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" TranslationX="20" TranslationY="-10" Padding="10,0" BackgroundColor="{TemplateBinding FrameColor}">
                    <Label x:Name="label" Text="{TemplateBinding LabelText}" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Default"/>
                </StackLayout>

            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66646722/199364, https://stackoverflow.com/q/60691598/199364. To make a control that can take different contents, see [Control Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template) or [Content Presenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentpresenter?view=xamarin-forms).

Answer (score 1):

One common way is to use `ContentView` to achieve this.

You can refer to the following code:

**EntryOutlined.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class EntryOutlined : ContentView
{
    public EntryOutlined()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(EntryOutlined), null);

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceholderProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Placeholder), typeof(string), typeof(EntryOutlined), null);

    public string Placeholder
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceholderColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PlaceholderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(EntryOutlined), Color.Blue);

    public Color PlaceholderColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(PlaceholderColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PlaceholderColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty BorderColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(EntryOutlined), Color.Blue);

    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value); }
    }


    
    public event EventHandler<TextChangedEventArgs> TextChanged;
    public virtual void OnTextChanged(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

}
```

**EntryOutlined.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinSamples.Views.Controls.EntryOutlined"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XamarinSamples.Views.Controls;assembly=XamarinSamples"
             Margin="{OnPlatform Android='3,0,3,5', iOS='3,0,3,5'}"
             x:Name="this">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout >
            <Grid >
                <Frame HasShadow="False"
                       x:Name="EntryFrame"
                       BorderColor="{Binding BorderColor, Source={x:Reference this}}"
                       CornerRadius="{OnPlatform Android=3}"
                       Padding="{OnPlatform Android='5,0,5,0', iOS='8,0,8,0'}"
                       Margin="{OnPlatform Android='0,10,0,0', iOS='0,0,0,0'}" />

                <Label x:Name="PlaceHolderLabel"
                       BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                       TextColor="Blue"
                       Text="Label"
                       Margin="10,0,0,0"       
                       VerticalOptions="Start" />

                <controls:BorderlessEntry
                    HeightRequest="{OnPlatform iOS=40,Android=50}"
                    x:Name="TextBox" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"                            
                    Text="{Binding Text,Source={x:Reference this},Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Margin="10,5,0,0"                            
                    Placeholder="{Binding Placeholder,Source={x:Reference this}}"
                    PlaceholderColor="{Binding PlaceholderColor, Source={Reference this}}"
                    TextChanged="OnTextChanged" />
            </Grid>            
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**BorderlessEntry.cs**

```
public class BorderlessEntry : Entry
{
    
}
```

**Usage**

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="Material Entry Outlined" 
           Margin="0,0,0,10"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="Center" />
    <controls:EntryOutlined 
        Placeholder=""
        BorderColor="Blue"
        PlaceholderColor="Green"
        TextChanged="EntryOutlined_OnTextChanged" />
</StackLayout>
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Luzanas, may I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.